# Reusable component is not working in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

My project folder structure is like below

[image]

I trying to use reusable component in my module. For that I'm using products component inside login component but it showing like below

> app-products' is not a known element:
>   1. If 'app-products' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>   2. If 'app-products' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("

And my home.module.ts is like below

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(HomeRoutingModule),
  ],
  declarations: [UserProfileComponent,ProductsComponent],
  exports:[ProductsComponent]
})
```

could any one please help in this regard how to solve this error

Comment: which Module the login component is declared in ?

Comment: app.module.ts consisting

Answer (score 2):

> Either you import `HomeModule` in `AppModule` or you must declare the `Login Component` in `HomeModule`.

```
imports: [
    HomeModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppModule
```

Answer (score 0):

Home module seems to be a common module not a root module - so if you want to use `components` or `directive` from that module you need to export those components - you have done correctly

Finally - angular will run on the root module you need to make sure that you are going to use this module in your application - so just import `HomeModule` in your `AppModule`

```
imports: [
    HomeModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class AppModule
```

This will stop lazy loading on `HomeModule` - to achieve lazy just bind components from common module by routing - hope this helps - Thanks happy coding !!